# Do Drivatars drive "your" car?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

In Forza 5 your Drivatar appears in other people's races. If you own a qualified car will it drive that car? Livery, tune, and all?

for example, if your Drivatar enters a Modern Grand Touring race and you own a GTR will it take ***that*** GTR(with Liveries and custom tune) or use a GTR or use any random car qualified for the league.

Comment: I think they'll drive a car in a given class, that you've used. I don't know for sure, but from seeing my friends drivatars it's not using cars they'd use a lot (ie. it's got one of my colleagues in a Ford, when he vehemently hates them). It's a bit too anecdotal and on a small sample size for me to be sure, though.